# Getting a custom logback appender to work inside a Dataflow job

Tags: logback, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a custom log appender defined in my logback.xml, which pushes data to an  Elasticsearch endpoint. Along with this, there are console and file appenders.

This xml, along with code, is part of a Dataflow job, and gets uploaded to Dataflow. I can see the log statements in the Dataflow logs in Stackdriver just fine, but the ES appender does not kick in. It looks like Google overrides all custom appenders with one that just writes to the Stackdriver logs.

Is there any way to use a custom log appender (e.g. with logback) inside Dataflow?

Related thread, not so helpful - https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/beam-user/201705.mbox/%3CCABnhQv_J0Qb5xnUdOhVdaDf4d8OE+f-AkZ2MrAruQgAAZ7XYGQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: I have the same problem, and also tried to force the SLF4JBridgeHandler but if I add the handler I receive an "infinite loop" of logs

Comment: I got in touch with the Dataflow team via their ticket support system, and their response is that this is not possible.